# .rigidbody in Unity 5

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When I've tried to use this code in Unity 5 it says that "isKinematic" function is no longer valid in Unity 5 or something like that.

Can someone explain why did they make such a change and how can I update my code to the right format?

```
rigidbody2D.isKinematic = false;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.rigidbody` and `.rigidbody2D` on a GameObject have been in the past convenience fields (shortcuts basically) to `.GetComponent<Rigidbody>()` and `.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>()`.

These convenience fields were eliminated in Unity 5.

The reason given is that it was more or less random whether these "shortcut" properties existed for any of the built-in components. Removing them all (except for Transform) makes things more consistent and less confusing.

Now you are "stuck" with accessing all the component (except Transform) explicitly:

```
GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().isKinematic = false;
```

Comment: If you are going to make this kind of call a lot then remember to save the result of GetComponent